# Remove new line characters from csv file and save results to the same filename

Tags: csv, ksh

I have files which have spaces in their filenames (ex filename `Listener Care - RXM Call Center Satisfaction-2022-03-01.csv`)
These files also have new line characters in the data they contain.
I have several such files in the input directory.
For each file, I want to remove new line characters and save the result to the same file.
example -
`Listener Care - RXM Call Center Satisfaction-2022-03-01.csv` --> remove new line characters --> save result to `Listener Care - RXM Call Center Satisfaction-2022-03-01.csv`

I want to do this process for each file in the input directory and then move these processed files to Archive directory.

I tried to use
`cat 'Listener Care - RXM Call Center Satisfaction-2022-03-01.csv'| gawk -v RS='"' 'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\n/, "") } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }' >/home/kold/Qual/modified/'Listener Care - RXM Call Center Satisfaction-2022-03-01.csv';`

This works for single file.

Please guide me how to make the solution work as per my requirements stated above.mI am using ksh.
Thank you.

Comment: Surely you don't want to remove ALL of the newline characters.  That would make the entire file one very long line.

Comment: This is a nice example why an example input and output can help. You seem to like to remove the newlines inside fields and not at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

The outputfile is already created before reading the input, so you need a temporary file. Something like

```
mydir='/home/kold/Qual/modified/'

    csv="${mydir}/Listener Care - RXM Call Center Satisfaction-2022-03-01.csv"
    tmpfile="${mydir}/${csv}.tmp"
    
    gawk -v RS='"' '
      NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\n/, "") }
      {
        printf("%s%s", $0, RT)
      }' "${csv}" > "${tmpfile} && mv "${tmpfile}" "${csv}"
```

Comment: Thank you @Walter A. This works and I agree with the first creating a tmp file. 
I realized that I need to run this code after doing sftp into a server. So, the shell script needs to sftp inside a server, go to mydir='/home/kold/Qual/modified/' and then run this code to remove new line characters inside feilds of the file. 
Can you please suggest how to tweak this code to achieve the result?

Comment: After the shell script establishes sftp connection to the server, it gives "Invalid Command" error for all lines of the code which used to remove new line characters.

Comment: This is a different question and hard to tell. Perhaps `gawk` is unknown, or you copied a file with `\r\n` line endings.